# Broadcast between services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to send a broadcast from one service to another

```
.factory('BetSlipFactory', function()

  removeSlip: function(slip) {

    $rootScope.$broadcast('removeSlip:betSlipFactory');

    return betSlipSelectionRequest('/betSlip/removeSelection', {
      game: slip.game,
      pair: slip.pair,
      line: slip.line
    });
  }
})
```

What I need: when `removeSlip` it's been called, I need to call this function named `getLines`

```
  .factory('LinesFactory', function($q, $http, $rootScope, CONSTANT_VARS) {

   //THIS IS THE SERVICE WHERE I NEED TO CALL GETLINES
   //FROM THE BROADCAST

    return {
      getLines: function(params, selections) {

        $http.post(CONSTANT_VARS.BACKEND_URL + '/lines/lines', params)
          .success(function(lines) {
                console.log(lines)
            });
      }...
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service instead of a factory and register callbacks with the service.

Comment: please provide a detailed answer. this is a comment